# Backreference in regular expression doesn't work

Tags: android, regex, backreference

I am using this simple code:

```
if (data.matches("(\\d+)\\D+"))
   data = "$1";
```

I want to find a string that begins with a number and then have non-number string. I need to extract the number itself.
The backreference doesn't work. I am getting that data equals literally $1 instead of the matched expression.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read from a file: 0 and endless of unreadable characters... and I only want the number.

Comment: Well, you can't use back-references like that. If you want to access matched data outside the pattern, you need to use Pattern and Matcher classes.

Comment: @Rohit thanks! Can you write a code example that will be the same as I want?

Comment: Go through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) and [this too](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regexjava). `matcher.group(1)` will have your number.